# RegEx replace not updating values in Range Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I want to add a regex pattern from a dialog box

In this particular example, I have cell values like `stuff Gr=something` and I am removing the `Gr=something` with the pattern `/(\s*Gr=).*/` which works using the function below

I have

```
function upDateStrRegEx_n() {
  const a = /(\s*Gr=).*/
  upDateStrRegEx(a)

}

function upDateStrRegEx(text) {
  const ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht    = ss.getSheetByName("UniqueList_(ignore)");
  const LR     =  sht.getLastRow(); 
  const rng    = sht.getRange("D2:D"+LR);
  var v = rng.getValues(); 

  v = v.map(e => [e[0].replace(text,"")])

  sht.getRange(2,4,v.length,1).setValues(v)
}
```

But I want to set the RegEx pattern from a dialog box with

```
function replaceSubStr() {
    const ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sht    = ss.getSheetByName("UniqueList_(ignore)");
    const Header = sht.getRange("D1").getDisplayValue();
    var ui   = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    
    if(isRange("UniqueList_(ignore)", Header) == false) {
      ui.alert('No Range Column ~~> D');
      return
    }

    var result = ui.prompt("Enter RegEx Find Pattern for Column ~~> D",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var text   = result.getResponseText();

    if(button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      ss.toast('CANCELED');

    }else if (button == ui.Button.OK && text == "") {
       replaceSubStr()

    }else if (button == ui.Button.OK && text != "") {
      upDateStrRegEx(text)
      ss.toast('Updated');

    }else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
       ss.toast('Closed');

    };
}
```

but here

```
else if (button == ui.Button.OK && text != "") {
      upDateStrRegEx(text)
      ss.toast('Updated');

    }
```

will not work when the RegEx is set from the dialog

everything runs without error but the cell values are not changed

Thanks for any assistance with this

Goole sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ahJI6dtTeC4IdqhPhwMVxUexIhlZamKlsumwmPWnv8M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to use `new RegExp()` to create a regexp dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the text from the dialog into a regexp.

```
    } else if (button == ui.Button.OK && text != "") {
      upDateStrRegEx(new RegExp(text + '.*'))
      ss.toast('Updated');
    }
```

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the response but getting the same response.  Data is not updated. I added a Goole sheet with data and functions  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ahJI6dtTeC4IdqhPhwMVxUexIhlZamKlsumwmPWnv8M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what confused me with this, is, I was adding `/` to the regex.  It needed to be just `(\s*Gr=).*` NOT `/(\s*Gr=).*/`

Comment: Right, that's part of the syntax of regexp literals, not part of the regexp itself.